# I can't get over this error "undefined local variable or method `f' " Any reason why?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, local-variables

I am trying to get my submit button for to be on a different page but I get this error. I have the following in my show.html.erb,

```
<div class="post-page">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading-gray">
            <%= @user.name %> | <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Edit<%= link_to edit_post_path(@post) %></button> | <%= link_to 'Delete', post_path, method: :delete, data: { Confirm: "Are you sure?" } %><i class="fa fa-times"></i> </div>
        <div class="panel-body"><h3><%= @post.body %></h3></div>
           <div class="panel-footer">
            Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> Ago
           </div>
</div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Post</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <form>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
              <%= render 'form' %>
            </div>
      </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <%= f.submit %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

This is in my _form.html.erb page,

```
 <% form_for @post do |f| %>
    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
      <div id="errors">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "Error") %> Prevent this post from posting</h2>
        <ul>
            <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>

            <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <p>
         <%= f.label :body %><br>
         <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

This is in my posts_controller.rb,

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
end
def welcome
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @posts = Post.order("created_at desc").limit(4).offset(1)
    @signed_in_user = session[:user_id]
end
def new 
    @post = Post.new
end
def create         
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    @post.user_id = @signed_in_user

if  @post.save 
    redirect_to dashboard_path 
else
    render 'new'
end
end
def show
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @posts = Post.order("created_at desc").limit(4).offset(1)
    @signed_in_user = session[:user_id]

end
def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:body))
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.user_id = @signed_in_user

    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_path
end

private
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:body)
end
end
```

I have even tried rendering partials thinking that maybe it could help, I have tried several things overall but can't seem to figure this out. I am sure its very simple and I am missing it but if you know how to fix it then post your answer and thank you in advance! I can also add any other code you may need to see that can help this process!

Comment: Why are you not just using the submit within your form? f is not available outside your form with your setup, that's why you get the error...

Comment: Can you please explain in detail? I only added the things from my html that are giving me the errors, I can tell you that they are within the same form.

Comment: It's not, you are rendering your form as a partial which is ok but you end the form too... Remove your button after the render partial and see what happens

Comment: That did absolutely nothing

Comment: Did you add an = aswell as suggested in other answers

Comment: I added it, It didn't work. I took it off, It didn't work.

Comment: Can you post your code with the form using = and the removal of the button outside your form

Comment: your rendering the form within a modal, that changes things, look at https://coderwall.com/p/ej0mhg/open-a-rails-form-with-twitter-bootstrap-modals You also have some html errors, like a form tag wrapping your actual form, form_for creates this tag for you

Answer (score 2):

`f` is only available in the `form_for` block, which is being prematurely closed with the first `<% end %>`.

```
<% form_for @post do |f| %>
      </div>
    <% end %> <!-- Closes form_for; remove this line  -->
    <p>
         <%= f.label :body %><br>
         <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

**Edit:**

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><%= f.submit %></button>` in show.html.erb is also outside of the context of the form block. Move this line to _form.html.erb, before the closing `<% end %>` and your error should disappear.

This will solve the error, but your form will not be output unless you modify the opening tag as [Eifion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11281/eifion) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651743/i-cant-get-over-this-error-undefined-local-variable-or-method-f-any-reason/28651928#28651928).

Comment: That wasn't the issue

Comment: It hasn't changed the issue, I still have the same error

Comment: @genobambino I've added to the answer.

Comment: I just tried it and still I have the same error. Like I said, If you need to see anymore of my code I can edit my question!

Comment: @genobambino Do you have the extracted source showing the specific line triggering the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
```

with an equals sign instead of

```
<% form_for @post do |f| %>
```

on the first line of your partial.

Comment: This also was not the problem, I have the same error still.